# Grails unit testing help needed

Tags: unit-testing, grails

I want to test a Grails controller which calls a service.  I'd like to mock the service.  The Service has a method:

`JobIF JobServiceIF.getJob(int)`

and JobIF has a method:

`String JobIF.getTitle()`

Here's my controller

```
def workActivities = {
   JobIF job = jobService.getJob(params.id)
   [career:job]
}
```

I understand that I need to mock the service and the job class (there are concrete implementations for both) but I'm struggling to get my head around the Groovy mocking object syntax.  How do I mock a job and set the title to something, say "Architect" and then test the code?

So far I have:

```
void testWorkActivities() {
   def controller = new CareersController()
   ... // Mocking stuff I don't know how to do
   controller.params.id = 12
   def model = controller.workActivities()
   assertEquals "Architect", model["career"].getTitle()
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You basically have two choices

1. Use the Groovy mocking classes, i.e. `MockFor` and `StubFor`
2. Use the Grails mock classes by calling the `mockFor` method of `GrailsUnitTestCase`. The class returned by this method is an instance of `GrailsMock`

Personally, I have found the Groovy mock objects to a bit more reliable than the Grails mocks. On occasions, I've found that my Grails mock objects were bypassed, even though I appeared to be setting everything up correctly.

Here's an example of how to use the Groovy mocks:

```
void testCreateSuccess() {

    def controller = new CareersController()

    // Create a mock for the JobService implementation class
    def mockJobServiceFactory = new MockFor(JobService)

    mockJobServiceFactory.demand.getJob {def id ->
        // Return the instance of JobIF that is used when the mock is invoked
        return new Job(title: "architect")
    }

    // Set the controller to use the mock service
    controller.jobService = mockJobServiceFactory.proxyInstance()

    // Do the test
    controller.params.id = 12
    def model = controller.workActivities()
    assertEquals "Architect", model["career"].getTitle()
}
```

The process is basically the same when using the Grails mocks, but you call the `mockFor` method of the test class, instead of instantiating `MockFor`.

Comment: Thanks. Can I ask one more question?  If the JobService has a constructor argument - how do I specify that?  For example JobService takes a JobDao as it's constructor arg.  Thanks.

Comment: The stacktrace by the way is:

Testcase: testWorkActivities took 0.344 sec
 Caused an ERROR
Could not find which method <init>() to invoke from this list:
  public uk.co.cascaid.biz.job.JobObservableCachedService#<init>(uk.co.cascaid.dao.job.JobDaoIF, uk.co.cascaid.biz.common.paging.PageCollectionServiceIF)
  public uk.co.cascaid.biz.job.JobObservableCachedService#<init>(uk.co.cascaid.dao.job.JobDaoIF)
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MethodSelectionException: